# Calculating and plotting monthly average indices for a region from Landsat data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, graph

I am trying to calculate the monthly average MNDISI for the 2020 period using Landsat data and then plot the values onto a graph (averaging all images in each month of each year separately across the full period). However, I keep getting the following error:

> Line 185: mndisi.filterDate is not a function

You can see the code I am using below.

```
var jawa = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-tugasakhirkkh/assets/Daerah_Penelitian");
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
Map.centerObject(jawa,7);
Map.addLayer(jawa,{},'Batas Administrasi Pulau Jawa',false);

//Define Research Time
  var start = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
  var end = ee.Date('2020-12-31');

//Time Variable
var n_days = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'day')).round();
var n_months = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'month')).round();
var n_years = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'year')).round();
print('Days = ', n_days);
print('Months = ', n_months);
print('Year = ', n_years);

//Cloud Mask
  function maskL8Clouds(image) {
    // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
      var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
      var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();  
      // Get the pixel QA band.
      var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
      // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
      var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
    // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
    return image.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
  }
  
//Define Dataset
  //---------------Landsat 8 Dataset---------------
  var imageL8 = L8
                .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',90)
                .map(maskL8Clouds)
                .filterDate(start,end)
                .filterBounds(jawa)
                .map(function(image) {
                return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
                })
                .mosaic()
                .clip(jawa);
                  
//LST Function Indices
  //Calculate NDVI (ndvi)
    {
    var ndvi = imageL8.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
    var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue']};
    Map.addLayer(ndvi,ndviParams, 'NDVI',false);
    }
    
  //Select Band 10 as Brightness Temperature (BT)
    {
    var BT= imageL8.select('B10').multiply(0.1).rename('BT');
    print('Brightness Temperature',BT)
    }
    
  // Find Min and Max NDVI
    {
    var min_ndvi = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: jawa,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
    }).values().get(0));
    print('NDVI Min', min_ndvi);
    
    var max_ndvi = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: jawa,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
    }).values().get(0));
    print('NDVI Max', max_ndvi)
    }

  //Calculate the Proportion of Vegetation (pv)
    {
    var pv =(ndvi.subtract(min_ndvi).divide(max_ndvi.subtract(min_ndvi))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('PV'); 
    print('Proportion of Vegetation', pv);
    }
  
  //Calculate Emissivity (E)
    {
      var a = (0.004);
      var b = (0.986);
      var E = pv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('E');
      print('Emissivity',E);
    }
    
  //Calculate LST (lst)
  {
    var lst = imageL8.expression(
              '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15',
              {'Tb': BT.select('BT'),
               'Ep': E.select('E')
              }).rename('LST');
    var lst_param = {min:20, max:40, palette:['040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
                    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
                    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
                    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
                    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003']};
    Map.addLayer(lst,lst_param,'LST Mean Tahunan', false);
  }

//MNDWI Function Indices
  //Calculate MNDWI
  {
    var mndwi = imageL8.expression(
                '(Green - SWIR)/(Green + SWIR)',
                   {'Green': imageL8.select('B3'),
                    'SWIR': imageL8.select('B6')
                   }).rename('MNDWI');
    var mndwiParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301']};
    Map.addLayer(mndwi,mndwiParams, 'MNDWI',false);      
  }
  
//MNDISI Function Indices
  //Calculate MNDISI
  {
    var mndisi = imageL8.expression(
                '(LST - ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))/(LST + ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))',
                   {'LST': lst.select('LST'),
                    'MNDWI': mndwi.select('MNDWI'),
                    'NIR' : imageL8.select('B5'),
                    'SWIR': imageL8.select('B6')
                   }).rename('MNDISI');
    var mndisiParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301']};
    Map.addLayer(mndisi,mndisiParams, 'MNDISI');
  }

//Create Legend
  //CreatePalette
function makeColorBarParams(palette) {
  return {
    bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
    dimensions: '200x20',
    format: 'png',
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: palette,
  };
}

//Create ColorBar
var colorBar = ui.Thumbnail({
  image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0),
  params: makeColorBarParams(mndisiParams.palette),
  style: {stretch: 'vertical', margin: '0px 8px', maxHeight: '24px'},
});

//Create Panels
var legendLabels = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Label(mndisiParams.min, {margin: '4px 5px', textAlign: 'left'}),
    ui.Label(mndisiParams.max, {margin: '4px 170px', textAlign: 'right'})
  ],
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')
});

var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'Average MNDISI',
  style: {fontWeight: 'bold'}
});

//Show Legend
var legendPanel = ui.Panel([legendTitle, colorBar, legendLabels]);
Map.add(legendPanel);

//Time Variable
var n_days = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'day')).round();
var n_months = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'month')).round();
var n_years = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'year')).round();
print('Days = ', n_days);
print('Months = ', n_months);
print('Year = ', n_years);

//Create Monthly Plotting Chart Terra
var months = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0,n_months).map(function(n){
    var start_month = start.advance(n,'months');
    var end_month = start_month.advance(1,'month');
    return mndisi.filterDate(start_month,end_month)
                     .select(0).mean()
                     .set('system:time_start', start_month);
  }));
  
var terra_month_2020 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: months,
  region:jawa,
  scale:1000,
  xProperty:'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
    title:'Average Monthly MNDISI in 2020',
    vAxis:{title:'MNDISI'},
    hAxis:{title:'Months'}
  });
print(terra_month_2020,'MNDISI');
```

From checking the GEE script, I assumed this was a minor issue and have fixed those issues, so I am not sure why the code is still failing.

Comment: Your property 'mndisi' is an `image`, not an `imageCollection`; it's calculated using `.expression()`, which returns an `image`. Only the latter you can filter by date using `.filterDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is produced because **mndisi** is an image and you are using 'filterDate' for Image Collections. Your code works with this modification.

```
//Create Monthly Plotting Chart Terra
var months = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0,n_months).map(function(n){
    var start_month = start.advance(n,'months');
    var end_month = start_month.advance(1,'month');
    return mndisi//.filterDate(start_month,end_month)
                     .select('MNDISI')
                     .set('system:time_start', start_month);
  }));
```

However, running it in GEE code editor produces following (probably) unexpected result for you. You need to fix other things in your code.

[image]